# How can I add boost_signalsConfig.cmake to my CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH

Tags: boost, cmake, ros, catkin, boost-signals

I'm running ROS-kinetic on Ubuntu 16.04 and I am trying to build two packages in a catkin workspace ([lanelet2](https://github.com/fzi-forschungszentrum-informatik/Lanelet2) & [mrt_cmake_modules](https://github.com/KIT-MRT/mrt_cmake_modules))

When I run Catkin_make in the workspace, I receive the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.70.0/BoostConfig.cmake:95 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "boost_signals"
  (requested version 1.70.0) with any of the following names:

    boost_signalsConfig.cmake
    boost_signals-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "boost_signals" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "boost_signals_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "boost_signals" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it
  has been installed.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /usr/local/lib/cmake/Boost-1.70.0/BoostConfig.cmake:124 (boost_find_dependency)
  /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:245 (find_package)
  mrt_cmake_modules/cmake/Modules/FindAutoDeps.cmake:120 (find_package)
  lanelet2/lanelet2_core/CMakeLists.txt:19 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

I do have the boost library installed (Version 1.58):

```
dpkg -s libboost-all-dev | grep 'Version'
Version: 1.58.0.1ubuntu1
```

I can't seem to find either `boost_signalsConfig.cmake` or `boost_signals-config.cmake` anywhere in my system so I can't add the path to `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`.

Could someone please tell me how to get these .cmake files so I can add them to my `CMAK_PREFIX_PATH`?

Comment: You might try setting the CMake variable `Boost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE` to `OFF` when providing CMake arguments: `-DBoost_NO_BOOST_CMAKE=OFF`

Comment: "I do have the boost library installed (Version 1.58)" - According to the error location, you have Boost **1.70** installed under `/usr/local/`. Please, recheck which Boost you actually have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @Tsyvarev for pointing out the issue. After looking at my /usr/local/ directory, I saw that libboost 1.70 was still installed so I deleted all files related to libboost 1.70 in /usr/local/lib/ and /usr/local/include. Everything compiled fine after doing this.